# how to show and hide the textarea based on the selected option from dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

i have a jquery code that is used in order to show or hide specified textarea based on the user selection form the dropdownlist where each option will show the related textarea to it .

## Jquery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
          jQuery("#textarea").hide()
          jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
        //  jQuery(this).val() == 'select' ? jQuery("#textarea").hide() : jQuery("#textarea").show();
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
              if(value=="category 1" ){
                  jQuery("#option2").show();
              }
              else if (value=="category 2"){
                  jQuery("#option3").show();
              }
              else if (value=="category 3"){
                  jQuery("#option4").show();
              }

          });
        });
      </script>
```

## HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group  ">
                      <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                               <option  value="select"  selected>Select</option>
                               <option  value="category 1">category 34</option>
                               <option  value="category 2">category 2</option>
                               <option  value="category 3">category 3</option>
                           </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
    <div id="textarea">
                          <div class="form-group  ">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <textarea id ="textareaID34" name="textareaName34" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 34 "> </textarea>
                              <textarea id ="textareaID2" name="textareaName2" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 2 "> </textarea>
                              <textarea id ="textareaID3" name="textareaName3" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text  3"> </textarea>                       
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: should `#option3` be equal to `textareaID3` ? Please include all relevant code, aka your dropdown html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i edit my question and add the dropdownlist  html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("textarea").hide()
  jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
    //  jQuery(this).val() == 'select' ? jQuery("#textarea").hide() : jQuery("#textarea").show();
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("textarea").hide()
    if (value == "category 1") {
      jQuery("#textareaID2").show();
    } else if (value == "category 2") {
      jQuery("#textareaID3").show();
    } else if (value == "category 3") {
      jQuery("#textareaID34").show();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  ">
  <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                               <option  value="select"  selected>Select</option>
                               <option  value="category 1">category 34</option>
                               <option  value="category 2">category 2</option>
                               <option  value="category 3">category 3</option>
                           </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="textarea">
  <div class="form-group  ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea id="textareaID34" name="textareaName34" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 34 "> </textarea>
      <textarea id="textareaID2" name="textareaName2" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 2 "> </textarea>
      <textarea id="textareaID3" name="textareaName3" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text  3"> </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A smart way of doing it is this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("textarea").hide()
  jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("textarea").hide();
    jQuery("#" + value).show();
  });
});
```

But then you have to change each option value a bit.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("textarea").hide()
  jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("textarea").hide();
    jQuery("#" + value).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  ">
  <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                               <option  value="select"  selected>Select</option>
                               <option  value="textareaID34">category 34</option>
                               <option  value="textareaID2">category 2</option>
                               <option  value="textareaID3">category 3</option>
                           </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="textarea">
  <div class="form-group  ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea id="textareaID34" name="textareaName34" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 34 "> </textarea>
      <textarea id="textareaID2" name="textareaName2" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text 2 "> </textarea>
      <textarea id="textareaID3" name="textareaName3" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text  3"> </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes  that is exactly what i want but can you explain what you did in jquery ?

this line i did not understand : jQuery("#" + value).show();

Comment: "value" variable will contain the selected text in dropdown list. so if you select for Eg: "textareaID3"  this will become "#textareaID3" using "# + value" , and "jQuery("#" + value).show();" this will show the "textareaID3".

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn thanks for the explanation, i was away for a few min +1

Answer (score 0):

**With just small modifications, Here is working example of what you want:**

[Preview on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q257bsd/)

```
 jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("textarea").hide()
      jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
    //  jQuery(this).val() == 'select' ? jQuery("#textarea").hide() : jQuery("#textarea").show();
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
          if(value=="category 1" ){
              jQuery("textarea").hide()
              $("#textareaID34").show();
          }
          else if (value=="category 2"){
              jQuery("textarea").hide()
              jQuery("#textareaID2").show();
          }
          else if (value=="category 3"){
              jQuery("textarea").hide()
              jQuery("#textareaID3").show();
          }

      });
    });
```

Hope it helps.